# RoR Ransack Searching issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controllers, ransack

I have two different controllers (scholarships_controller, scholarships_browse_controller) that look at the scholarship model.  I want my Ransack search function to show the search results on the current page.  So, for example, if I am on /scholarships_browse and I use the search functionality, I want it to use the scholarships_browse_controller and show the results on /scholarships_browse.

Currently, if I search on /scholarships_browse it uses the scholarships_controller and redirects to /scholarships to show the results (instead of /scholarships_browse).

**Code for ScholarshipsBrowseController and ScholarshipsController**

```
def index  
    @search = Scholarship.search(params[:q])
    @scholarships = @search.result.page(params[:page]).per(3)  #allows 3 scholarships on a page at a time
    @search.build_condition

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @scholarships }
    end
```

end

**Code for scholarships browse index.html.erb:**

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
    <%= f.condition_fields do |c| %>
        <div class="field">
            <%= c.attribute_fields do |a| %>
                <%= a.attribute_select %>
            <% end %>
            <%= c.predicate_select compounds: false, only: [:cont, :eq, :gt, :lt] %>
            <%= c.value_fields do |v| %>
                <%= v.text_field :value %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Search" %></div>
<% end %>
```

So, I guess specifically I'm asking how do I make sure I am using the ScholarshipsBrowseController index instead of ScholarshipsController index when I am on /scholarships_browse ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On your view:

```
<%= search_form_for @search, url: RAILS_ROUTEHERE do |f| %>
...
<%- end %>
```

**search_form_for** its an extension for `form_for`, so you can use the `:url` parameter to tell the form what should be the action of it (you can check the page source code when you render it on browser, you can check the tag `<form action="">` to make sure it points to the right route.

Comment: Cool, if my answer helped you, I would appreciate a positive vote and selecting my answer as accepted. Thx